# svn: ignoring files and folders

Tags: svn, maven, ignore

I've installed Visual svn and subslipse plugin. Then I created repository fro my Maven project and now I want to commit data. In Maven project I have folder named target with compilled files (by the way I have three project with dependencies). All I want is to igrnore files in "target@ folders. When I had java project I clicked on the project and add property svn:ignore with .class or target* value ... but id doen't work now!!! Why? And I can only add that property to main project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-Click on the relevant folder, select Team -> Add to svn:ignore

Comment: OK, can you download something like TortoiseSVN, and try the same thing from outside Eclipse? That's how I normally manage SVN projects.